# Is it beneficial(in terms of memory & space complexity) to write a few lines of code into a single line. Is it worth it?

Tags: java, c++, c

Example: Simple program of swapping two nos.

```
 int a = 10;
 int b = 20;
 a = a+b;
 b = a-b;
 a = a-b;
```

Now in the following piece of code:

```
 a=a+b-(b=a);
```

I mean What is the difference b/w these two piece of codes?

Addition : What if the addition of these two exceed the legitimate limit of an Integer which is different in case of Java & C++?

Comment: Your question appears to be incomplete... were you planning on asking something?

Comment: Usually simplicity and clarity is more important than performance. Not only is it more maintainable but it is also more likely to be optimised optimally. What is confusing for a human can be confusing for the optimiser.

Comment: I am a compiler.  I don't care what your code looks like...  Just tell me what to do.

Comment: Aside from anything else, that last one-liner has undefined behavior in C++ and C because the read of `b` in `a+b` is unsequenced relative to the assignment to `b` in `b=a`. Signed integer overflow is UB in C++ and C, but in practice implementations *might* define the behavior to wrap around, especially with low levels of optimization. Swapping without using a temporary variable (or a library function that itself can use one) is pretty much always incorrect. Even in Java, where I think this code's behavior is defined and correct, it's pointless to avoid the temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple points:

- Code should first reflect your *intentions*. After all, it's meant for humans to read. After that, if you really really must, you can start to tweak the code for performance. Most of all never write code to demonstrate a gimmick or bit twiddling hack.
- Breaking code onto multiple lines has absolutely no impact on performance.
- Don't underestimate the compiler's optimizer. Just write the code as intuitively as possible, and the optimizer will ensure it has the best performance.

In this regard, the most descriptive, intuitive, fastest code, is:

```
std::swap(a, b);
```

Answer (score 5):

Neither of these looks good to me. Readability is key. If you want to swap values, the most "obvious" way to do it is via a temporary value:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

int tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
```

I neither know nor would I usually care whether this was as efficient as the "clever" approaches involving arithmetic. Until someone proves that the difference in performance is significant *within a real application*, I'd aim for the simplest possible code that works. Not just here, but for all code. Decide how well you need it to perform (and in what dimensions), test it, and change it to be more complicated but efficient *if you need to*.

(Of course, if you've got a `swap` operation available within your platform, use that instead... even clearer.)

Comment: maybe a small thing to add: swapping ints by substraction/addition is likely to be UB due to overflow, so using a temp variable is the only good way.

Comment: Hi, But I save memory if I use one variable (tmp) less.

Comment: @JatinSehgal if you program depends on the temporary 4 bytes (which will probably be optimised away anyway, possibly moved to a register), you probably need to re-think it.

Comment: @JatinSehgal: Do you care? It'll probably all end up in registers. Do you have *any evidence whatsoever* that the difference would be significant in terms of performance? Compare that with the difference in readability.

Comment: @JatinSehgal if you are in an environment where you have to care about four (or eight) bytes stack space, you should probably switch to ASM.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Actually its just a trivial of examples that came to my mind. My actual question is does it help in anyway but readability if I replace a piece of code in multiple lines with a single line? That's all.

Comment: @JatinSehgal I guess that depends. Having, say, `a = b + c + d;` is probably better than `a = b; a += c; a += d`, plus it saves screen-space. Performance-wise, they'd still be the same though.

Comment: @JatinSehgal: It entirely depends on the *actual context*. See the advice at the end of my answer: use the simplest code that works, and test the performance.

Comment: Having written code simply, would always help avoiding bugs as well as figuring them out. One quality of a well written program vs a poor program is often that poor program is so complex for achieving simple tasks that you get lost in understanding the details and hence can't just where it went wrong.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, the code yields undefined behavior because there's no sequence point in `a+b-(b=a)` and you're changing `b` and reading from it.

You're better off using `std::swap(a,b)`, it is optimized for speed and **much more readable** than what you have there.

Comment: In C++ sequence points are gone. Now you have the harder to understand/explain concepts of sequenced-before and sequenced-after.

Comment: @6502 I wouldn't call them gone. C++03 is still in much much wider use than C++11.

Comment: Its not about swap. Its about writing a piece of code. Does it make an impact ,except readability of-course, if I write a code in a single which was earlier written in multiple lines

Comment: @JatinSehgal excluding readability, no. But it really depends on the piece of code, since in C++ you can overload operators. It gets tricky.

Answer (score 5):

Since your specific code is already commented upon, i would just add a general aspect. Writing one liners doesn't really matter because *at instruction level, you cannot escape the number of steps your assembly is going to translate into machine code. Most of the compilers would already optimize accordingly.*

That is, unless the one liner is actually using a different mechanism to achieve the goal for e.g. in case of swapping two variables, if you do not use a third variable and can avoid all the hurdles such as type overflow etc. and use bitwise operators for instance, then you might have saved one memory location and thereby access time to it.

In practice, *this is of almost no value and is trouble for readability* as already mentioned in other answers. Professional programs need to be maintained by people so they should be easy to understand.

One definition of good code is **Code actually does what it appears to be doing**

Even you yourself would find it hard to fix your own code if it is written cleverly in terms of some what shortened but complex operations. Readability should always be prioritized and most of the times, the real needed efficiency comes from improving design, approach or better data structures/algorithms, than instead short - one liners.

Quoting **Dijkstra**: *The competent programmer is fully aware of the limited size of his own skull. He therefore approaches his task with full humility, and avoids clever tricks like the plague.*

Answer (score 1):

Readability and instant understand-ability is what I personally rate (and several others may vote for) when writing and reading code.  It improves maintainability.  In the particular example provided, it is difficult to understand immediately what the author is trying to achieve in those few lines.
The single line code:`a=a+b-(b=a);` although very clever does not convey the author's intent to others obviously.

In terms of efficiency, optimisation by the compiler will achieve that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of java at least i remember reading that the JVM is optimized for normal straight forward uses so often times you just fool yourself if you try to do stuff like that.

Moreover it looks awful.

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this. Next time you have a strange bug, start by squashing up as much code into single lines as you can.

Wait a couple weeks so you've forgotten how it's supposed to work.

Try to debug it.

Comment: thts about readability I understand. I asked in terms of performance specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depends on the compiler. Although I cannot foresee any kind of earth-shattering difference. Abstruse code is the main one.